# How to set a CheckBox or RadioButton

Tags: android, android-widget

I looked at the documentation for CheckBox and I see these two methods:

```
setEnabled(boolean)
setSelected(boolean)
```

So, in my code, I put

```
CheckBox myCB = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.CheckBox);
myCB.setEnabled(true);
myCB.setSelected(true);
```

When I run the code, I want the above CheckBox to already be checked and turned 'on' in the GUI.  But it isn't.  It looks like it's unchecked.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setChecked(boolean checked)` or `toggle()` instead. Take a look at the javadoc for CheckBox [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html).

Notice that, for instance, `setSelected(boolean selected)` is inherited from TextView, and is used to determine the presentation of the text, not to check or uncheck the CheckBox.

Comment: I used setChecked() and that worked.  I have a question.  How can I figure these things out for myself?  I did already look at the CheckBox docs before I asked, and there's no setChecked() method.  How can I tell beforehand how to do simple things like this?

Comment: Oh, forgot.  Thanks!  At least I got something accomplished today!

Comment: Hey @JB_User, no worries. CheckBox inherits from CompoundButton, and that class defines setChecked().You should find out how to view javadoc through your IDE (Eclipse, or, as I use, Intellij IDEA). It's much faster than going online and searching each time. You can usually just click on the method/field/class, and hit a keystroke to bring them up. Alternatively, just make sure you expand the "Inherited Methods" section. The only methods shown by default in CheckBox are the methods defined in that class, not ones it inherits.

Comment: I'm not using the IDE so I have to look online for the documentation.

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and download a proper IDE, and learn how to use it. http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

Comment: I have the Eclipse IDE installed and working.  But the problems is there's so much for me to learn: Java, Android, Eclipse, etc.  At this point, it seems like Eclipse is getting in the way.  Especially when it doesn't do what I want it to do, I have to go edit the files anyway.

Comment: Try out IDEA maybe? You are right. I don't find Eclipse to be very intuitive, and the tool is cumbersome at first. But it will pay dividends.